# Admin permissions on IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I have developed an ASP.NET MVC application which executes few batch files. These batch files are performing multiple actions like handling TFS, copying files to remote machines which needs admin privileges. 
If I run the application from Visual studio with admin privileges, it works as expected. But same is not working on IIS. Have tried multiple options over IIS but still it's same. Can any one tell me what am I missing?

Comment: IIS has a concept called application pool identity.

Comment: @LexLi Yes Lex, have updated identity as application pool identity as well. But it also didn't work here.

Comment: very interesting. Have you tried to use Process Monitor to check?

Comment: @LexLi No, I didn't try that. Let me try that.

Comment: Change the application pool identity to Local System (this is equivalent to Admin) and see if it is working. If it works then put back the App pool identity to default (running app pool in Local System is not recommended) and use Process Monitor to check the Access Denied issue https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/chad/2009/12/30/how-to-use-sysinternals-process-monitor-and-process-explorer-to-troubleshoot-sharepoint/ . If it's not working under Local System it's mostly not permissions issue.